# C# Microsoft Fakes to test a method that is called in Constructor

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, shim

I want to test a public function in a Manager class. The problem is that that function is called inside the constructor of Manager class. So when I create a new instance of the Manager, so the function is also called.

Here I have 2 classes: one is Manager class, one is ManagerTest class to test the Manager.

Class Manager.cs

```
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(ILogger logger, IMonitor monitor)
    {
        //do stuff
        MethodNeedToBeTested();
    }

    public void MethodNeedToBeTested()
    {
    }
}
```

Class ManagerTest.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class ManagerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataTestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimManager.AllInstances.MethodNeedToBeTested = ()=>
            {
                //shim method here
            };
            Manager mng= new Manager(_logger, _monitor);
            mng.MethodNeedToBeTested(); // the problem is that this line goes directly to the shim above, it doesn't go to the real MethodNeedToBeTested()
     }
}
```

So basically, I just want to shim the method MethodNeedToBeTested() for the first time (when the constructor is called).

The second time when the method MethodNeedToBeTested is called, it goes to real MethodNeedToBeTested() function, not to the Shim

Comment: Maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99edf49e-4f75-4bbe-a5e0-b788f783cb36/detouring-constructor-in-microsoft-fakes?forum=vstest) will help you.